# Doesnt symmetrize in object or pose mode (rigging)

Tags: modeling, rigging, edit-mode, bones, pose-mode

Hello everyone please tell me one moment. I can't deal with him. I'm looking through the lessons on rigging and I can't get what is shown in the video. The bottom line is this: I have already made bones on half of the dummy's body. Further in the video it says that in Edit mode you need to select them all and click symmetrize. I press and symmetry appears, but only in Edit mode. If I switch to Pose mode or Object mode, then there is nothing in place of that symmetry. I switch back to Edit mode and everything is in place. I don't understand what the reason is.
[image]

Comment: My guess is that there is a pose active. If it looks ok in *Edit* mode, then switch to *Pose* mode, select all bones (key A) and clear their transformation (Alt+R, Alt+G, Alt+S or menu *Pose > Clear Transform > All* (you can assign a shortcut like Alt+T with right click)

Comment: nope,doesnt work

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: yeah, sure, here is a link  https://disk.yandex.ru/d/RaPi3pr6CC_1SQ

Answer (score 1):

Your rig has 3 bone layers (1, 2, 3). One layer 1 there are the deformation bones (*def-...*) that you want to symmetrize. Layer 2 seems to be a copy of layer 1. All these bones have a *.001* suffix. And Layer 3 has target bones (*tgt-...*).

There are two problems:

1. there are *Copy Transformation* bone constraints that move the created "right" deformation bones from the character's right side to the left side in *Object* and *Pose* mode.
   [image: bone contraints]
2. the target bones are not symmetric and you cannot symmetrize them because the suffixes have all an extra space character appended (`.l`  instead of `.l`)
   [image: renaming bones]

You need to remove the extra space character first and symmetrize the target bones. Then you can symmetrize the deformation bones without any problems.

With *Batch Rename* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) in the main menu *Edit* you can remove the extra space (*Find* `.l`  and *Replace* `.l`. There should be a message like *"27 bones renamed"* in the status bar). Then select all bones, symmetrize them, and finally, you can symmetrize the deformation bones. Blender will create the correct bone constraints for them.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!! it works!!! finally!